# Integrating an absolute value on exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

This might be a bit rusty but hopefully it can be brushed up.

I need to integrate 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-2\lambda \left | x \right |}dx$$

Recall:

$$\left | x \right |=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x &x\geq 0 \\ 
 -x& x< 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Then,

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-t}^{0}xe^{-2\lambda(-x)}dx+\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{t}xe^{-2\lambda(x)}dx
$$

I would appreciate a nudge. Intuition suggest odd and even function have a role to play.
Absolute values are nasty.

Comment: As Ron Gordon explained, the answer slides out nicely given the fact the function is odd. But you should also be able to integrate $xe^{kx} $ (hint: by parts). Absolute values aren't too bad: you just need to split them up in their two cases (as you've done) and then look at each case as you would for any other normal question ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolute value is even, so exponential is even.  $x$ is odd.  Odd times even is odd.  Thus, an integral of an odd function about a symmetric interval is...

Comment: What the heck. It's zero!

Comment: @Mathematicing: bingo.

Comment: Well, technically it's 0 iff the two branches converge, since this is an improper integral.  Pretty sure that's the case iff $\lambda \ne 0$

Comment: @Alan: I think I know what you mean, but I do not know what a "branch" is nor how it converges.  I do know, though, that if $\lambda=0$, the integral is a Cauchy principal value defined as the limit of a symmetric finite interval.

Comment: @RonGordon If memory serves, "branch" refers to "branch cut". It is a concept/ method commonly employed in complex integrals.

Comment: @Mathematicing: I know what a branch cut is.  But this is not a complex integral.

Comment: I was using it in a nontechnical sense,  I meant the prt that goes from 0 to $\infty$ has to converge, as does the part from $-\infty$ to $0$.   Because $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx$  does not converge, even though it is odd